# Cannot read property '#<Object>' of undefined , after retriving onClick Custom React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm building a leaflet map that dipslay markers. These markers have additional data on them besides lat and long, (keys in this case)

I'm using  a custom react component from the react-leaflet repo. I can get multiple markers location, but when I try to retrieve the marker I clicked on and pass it to a child component I get

**Cannot read property '# < Object > ' of undefined**

I can pass **ALL the data** , without a problem though.

I get this error when I try to pass the **"clicked"** marker to the Card and Cartitle components.

What I've tried so far:

Inside the handleToggle function I did:

**index = this.props.places[index]**

but that is when I get the error above. What am I doing wrong?

P.D. Also, Im able to display **ALL** the data to the children components

```
import ...

const markers = [
  {
    key: 'P12345678',
    position: [37.786464, -122.411047],
    children: 'My first popup'
  },
  {
    key: 'M12345678',
    position: [40.689192, -74.044563],
    children: 'My second popup'
   },
];


class Mapper extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      lat: 29.761993,
      lng: -95.366302,
      zoom: 4,
      open: false,
      places: []
    }
  }

  handleToggle(index) {

    const self = this;

    self.setState({
      open: !this.state.open,
      places: markers
    });

    // index = this.props.places[index]

    console.log(this.state.places)


  }

  handleClose() {
    this.setState({
      open: false
    });
  }


  render() {

    const center = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng];

//Custom Marker Component

    const MyPopupMarker = ({ children, position }) => (

      <Marker
        onClick={this.handleToggle}
        position={position}
        places={this.state.places}
      >
        <Popup>
          <span>{children}</span>
        </Popup>

      </Marker>
    )

    MyPopupMarker.propTypes = {
      // children: MapPropTypes.func,
      // position: MapPropTypes.latlng,
    }

    //Custom Marker List Component

    const MarkerList = ({ markers }) => {

      const items = markers.map(({ key, ...props }) => (
        <MyPopupMarker key={key} {...props} />
      ))
      return <div style={{display: 'none'}}>{items}</div>

    }

    MarkerList.propTypes = {
        markers: MapPropTypes.array.isRequired,
    }

    // console.log('markers', markers)


    return (
      <div>
        <Map
          center={center}
          zoom={this.state.zoom}
          style={styles.map}>

          <TileLayer
            url='https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          />

          <MarkerList markers={markers} />

        </Map>

        <Drawer
          width={500}
          openSecondary={true}
          docked={false}
          open={this.state.open}
          onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({open})}
          containerStyle={styles.whitebox}
        >
    {
      markers.map((cf, k) => (
            <Card
              style={styles.appMedia}
              key={k}
              >

              <CardTitle
                titleStyle={styles.drawTitle}
                subtitleStyle={styles.drawTitle}
                title={cf.key}
                subtitle="Common Field Equipment"/>
            </Card>
          ))
    }

        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Mapper;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `handleToggle` method is the `onClick` handler for the `Marker` component. The `onClick` handlers in React pass a synthetic event object by default (More info on this [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)).

So the `index` passed into the `handleToggle` method will be that synthetic event object, which would not help you get the index of the marker from your `places` array. You would have to pass the index explicitly into your `handleToggle` method. To do this you would need to make the following changes:

1> Change the binding of the function in the constructor to:

```
this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this,index);
```

2> Pass the index explicitly in the `MyPopupMarker` component:

```
const MyPopupMarker = ({ children, position,index }) => (
<Marker
        onClick={()=>this.handleToggle(index)}
 ....
 )
```

3> Pass the index to the `MyPopupMarker` component in the `MarkerList` component

```
 const items = markers.map(({ key, ...props },i) => (
    <MyPopupMarker key={key}  index={i} {...props}/>
  ))
```

4> Access the index from the `places` array in the `state` object and not the `props` object.

```
handleToggle(index) {

    const self = this;

    self.setState({
      open: !this.state.open,
      places: markers
    });

    var selectedMarker = this.state.places[index];

    console.log(this.state.places)
  }
```

The reason for the error message **Cannot read property '# < Object > ' of undefined** was that you were trying to access the `places` array in the `props` object where it was `undefined`.

As an aside, I would like to point out that creating components inside the `render` method (the components `MyPopupMarker` and `MarkerList`) is not a good practice as these components would be created on every render which would be wasteful. It would be much more efficient if you declare them outside your `Mapper` component.
**Edit:**

To move the components out of `render` you need to pass the `handleToggle` function in as `props`. I have changed your code as follows:

The MyPopupMarker component: This component gets the `index` and the `handleToggle` function as props.

```
const MyPopupMarker = ({ children, position, index, handleToggle }) => (
  <Marker onClick={() => handleToggle(index)} position={position}>
    <Popup>
      <span>{children}</span>
    </Popup>
  </Marker>
);
```

The MarkerList component: This component gets the `handleToggle` function as props and passes it on to the `MyPopupMarker` component along with the `index`

```
const MarkerList = ({ markers, handleToggle }) => {
  const items = markers.map(({ key, ...props }, i) => (
    <MyPopupMarker key={key} {...props} index={i} handleToggle={handleToggle} />
  ));
  return <div >{items}</div>;
};
```

The Mapper component: This component passes the `handleToggle` function to the `MarkerList` component along with the `markers`

```
class Mapper extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      lat: 29.761993,
      lng: -95.366302,
      zoom: 4,
      open: false,
      places: []
    };
  }

  handleToggle(index) {
    const self = this;

    self.setState({
      open: !this.state.open,
      places: markers
    });

    // index = this.props.places[index]

    let selectedMarker = this.state.places[index];

    console.log(selectedMarker);
  }

  handleClose() {
    this.setState({
      open: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    const center = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng];


    let selectedMarker = this.state.places;

    return (
      <div>
        <Map center={center} zoom={this.state.zoom} style={styles.map}>
          <TileLayer
            url="https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
          />

          <MarkerList markers={markers} handleToggle={this.handleToggle} />
        </Map>

        <Drawer
          width={500}
          openSecondary={true}
          docked={false}
          open={this.state.open}
          onRequestChange={open => this.setState({ open })}
          containerStyle={styles.whitebox}
        >

          {selectedMarker.map((value, index) => (
            <Card style={styles.appMedia} key={index}>
              <CardTitle
                titleStyle={styles.drawTitle}
                subtitleStyle={styles.drawTitle}
                title={value.key}
                subtitle="Common Field Equipment"
              />
            </Card>
          ))}
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Mapper;
```

The full working example can be found at https://codesandbox.io/s/4r1yo07kw9

Comment: I see, so they were outside the render method initially. but the only way to "attach" the handletoggle function was to put them there. every time I try to write this function like let's say right after the last import statement I will get an error, hence why I put them after render. Anyway, let me try your solution. I'll get back to ya in a few minutes

Comment: You can always pass the function as a prop to the child component. So MyPopupMarker would become `const MyPopupMarker = ({ children, position, places, handleToggle }) =>{...}`

Comment: ok , when I do step 1... I get Line 49:  'index' is not defined  no-undef ... when I change this to this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this) ( does the backticks matter??) instead I get the right click on the console. but when I try to pass it to the Card and CardTitle components I get the same index not defined (which makes sense since there is no index anyway)

Comment: can you create a sandbox at codesandbox.io so that i can look at your code in detail?

Comment: I had to commented out the Drawer part, it seems codesandbox doesnt like it, you can see the map in module view

Comment: Nvm. Had to mess with codesandbox but i got it to display it correctly

Comment: Updated my answer with the code and the working codesandbox. Hope it helps!

Comment: Humm...sorry about the misunderstanding , but the console log part was working when you first answered the question (which I'm thankful for btw).
but you see how the drawer opens with 2 key values?...it's suppose to open with only 1 per click , which is the markers.key value

Comment: On line 97 if I replace 
let selectedMarker = this.state.places[index];, this doesnt work. thats my point, sorry about the confusion

Comment: have updated the sandbox with changes as per to show only one value.

Comment: Thank you very much, would you mind telling me what did you do at the end ?

Comment: in the toggle method, i saved the selected marker to the state. in the render method, i checked whether the selecetedmarker in the state was null or not. when not null, i used the selecedmarker to render the drawer and card. there was no need for the map function there as we needed to just render the selected card, so i removed it. hope that made sense!

Comment: Yes it does. Never thought about it that way, thanks sir